# Pass File Name and Location From SaveFileDialog To Variable

Tags: c#, winforms, epplus, savefiledialog

I have been just hard coding a save name/location, but now I need to ask the user for the save location and file name.  I have this syntax, but how do I actually pass the selected location & input file name to my `ToExcel()` method to know the file name and save locaiton?

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Creating Save File Dialog
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    //Showing the dialog
    save.ShowDialog();
    //Setting default directory
    save.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    save.RestoreDirectory = true;
    //Setting title
    save.Title = "Select save location and input file name";
    //filtering to only show .xml files in the directory
    save.DefaultExt = "xml";
    //Write Data To Excel
    ToExcel();
}

private void ToExcel()
{
    var file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "Test_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M-dd-yyyy-HH.mm.ss") + ".xlsx"));

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
        ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "One";
        ws.Cells["A1:C1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        package.Save();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use an OpenFileDialog to select an existing file, Save is for creating an non existent file, and FolderBrowserDialog to select a folder

Comment: also you say `//filtering to only show .xml files in the directory` this is not correct to filter you would use this code `openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;` DefaultExt is used to determine what extension to use if none is specified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly `ShowDialog` should be the last line of your call, after you have configured it

then use the FileName Property to access the selected Filename

finally pass that to whatever you need to pass it to ie

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    save.RestoreDirectory = true;
    save.Title = "Select save location file name";
    save.DefaultExt = "xml"; // surely should be xlsx??

    //Showing the dialog
    if(save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ToExcel(save.FileName);
    }
}
private void ToExcel(string saveFile){...}
```

also if you want to get the Directorty of a FileInfo check the [FileInfo.Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directory(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: Aww man, I did it with FileName and FileNames and you beat me.

Comment: I get a compile error of 'DialogResult' does not contain a definition for 'Ok'

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh try "save.ShowDialog() == true" - it's a c# 4.0 thing I believe.  Still a good answer imo, he just needs to update it for C# 4.0.

Comment: @Aaron - if I do if (save.ShowDialog() == true) I get a compile error of Operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type 'DialogResult' and 'bool'

Comment: What project type is this? Need more tags I guess... Winforms, ASP, etc? - I can't not make this work. You have Winforms imported for it, or something else? Are you using any 3rd party dll's?

Comment: @Aaron - it is winforms.  Using epplus dll (3rd party)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151969/discussion-between-aaron-and-bellhopbydayametuercoderbynigh).

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh sorry bell was a typo supposed to be OK all caps

Comment: @Aaron its not a c#4.0 thing its a winforms thing  `System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog` defines `public DialogResult ShowDialog()` your right that if he was using the `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog` then its defined as `public Nullable<bool> ShowDialog()`

Comment: @MikeT it was a grammar thing. Review chat.